# Web page is appearing blank

Tags: html, css

As a newbie, I am following a tutorial on youtube to make a simple website but I hit a brick wall from some simple html.  I am using `Atom` as my development area but thats not the problem because when I go to my filesystem and run my index.html file it just gives me a white screen.  As you can see in my code below all I have done is add a blue background.  Can someone point out any issues with my code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src='./script.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="blue-back"></div>

  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2"></div>
  <header>
  <span class="logo">PROCESS-STREET</span>
  <span class="hiring-text">We're hiring</span>
  </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `fluid-container` simply has no height, because it has no (visible) content.

Comment: Can we see your css as well?

Comment: @deceze Unless there's something set in the css about width and height.

Comment: Why don't you add some text and make sure you are calling the right page. Then start debugging the color problem

Comment: Add 100% height on body,html,fluid-container and blue-back

Comment: Just added some text but it is not being positioned correctly? But it shows in the browser so at least I know I am calling the right file

Comment: How do I incorporate 100% height....haven't got a clue as new to this literally just put my foot in the water

Answer (score 0):

The `fluid-container` needs to have something of visible height/width inside it. It can be just a simple `<p>Hello</p>`

Try replacing your code with this:

```
<div class="fluid-container">
     <div class="blue-back">
          <p>Hello world</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now the blue background will be there

Comment: still doesn't appear but the writing does

Comment: @squathub Yes because **p** or **div** by default does not have any size unless you mention in css. The writing takes up space hence the styling shows.

Comment: @squathub For example simply give styling like 

`div.blue-back{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10 px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. You have created `<div>` but there is not content inside, so default height and width is 0px
2. Also the class name 'blue-back' is not in bootstrap, make sure that you have created it in another css file.

Please check below example background `class` given by bootstrap:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src='./script.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="bg-primary">background is here</div>
    
    <p>Please check other example : </p>
   <p class="bg-primary text-white">This text is important.</p>
  <p class="bg-success text-white">This text indicates success.</p>
  <p class="bg-info text-white">This text represents some information.</p>
  <p class="bg-warning text-white">This text represents a warning.</p>
  <p class="bg-danger text-white">This text represents danger.</p>
  <p class="bg-secondary text-white">Secondary background color.</p>
  <p class="bg-dark text-white">Dark grey background color.</p>
  <p class="bg-light text-dark">Light grey background color.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A `div` is displayed as `block` by default, so it has *full width* but zero height…